# How to use Chessboard.js and Chess.js together in MeteorJS using BlazeJS?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, chess, chessboard.js

I have a fresh MeteorJS project and I have only installed [chessboardjs](https://chessboardjs.com/index.html) and [chessjs](https://libraries.io/bower/chess.js) as follows

```
meteor npm install --save chessboardjs
meteor npm install --save chess.js
```

In my client `main.js` I have also imported the above packages as follows;

```
import Chessboardjs from 'chessboardjs';
import Chessjs from 'chessjs';
```

According to chessboardjs documentation, the way to display a board is as follows;

For html

```
<div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>
```

and for JS

```
var board1 = Chessboard('board1', 'start')
```

My question is how do I get to display this in MeteorJS and how do I get the two chess npm packages to work together?

Any working examples will be highly appreciated.

Maybe I should also mention that the whole purpose is to have a two player game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues here.

1. Imports typo
2. importing css
3. Rendering

First your imports and the function you call need to be the same. You imports are

```js
import Chessboardjs from 'chessboardjs';
import Chessjs from 'chessjs';
```

but they should be

```js
import Chessboard from 'chessboardjs';
import Chessjs from 'chess.js';
```

Second, the npm package import usually not automatically imports the css as well. You need to actively locate it's path within the `node_modules/chessboardjs` folder and import it:

```js
import 'chessboardjs/www/css/chessboard.css'
```

Finally, the `Chessboard` function can't inject code into the DOM, if the target element (the div with id `board1`) has not been rendered, yet.

To fix this you need to call it within `onRendered`:

```js
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  var board1 = Chessboard('board1', 'start')
})
```

It won't work in `onCreated`, because the `onCreated` callback is called **before** the first time the Template has been rendered.

See http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered

Comment: I tried the above and it has rendered a page with chessboard numbers but the styling is missing. So how do I include styling?

Comment: I updated my answer, it's basically just adding one more line

Comment: The second part of the question was how do I integrate with `chess.js` so that I can validate the moves?

Comment: I think this would be beyond a single question. You can try a bit first on your own, for example trying to save the state and the moves in a reactive dict, and open a specific question when ypu get stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Jankapunkt you have been helpful.